# How do I print list items from two separate lists on the same line?

Tags: python, list, iteration, output

So in Python I have two lists of different float values, each list is assigned to a variable.

How do I go about printing each value from these lists vertically, but each on the same lines?

For instance:

```
list1      list2

-----      -----

5    ,       6

7     ,      8

9      ,     10
```

And so on and so forth?

Comment: zip(list1, list2) ?

Answer (score 5):

you can do it as this:

```py
print ('list1, list2')
for f,s in zip(list1, list2):
    print(f, ',', s)
```

without zip if they both have the same legnth:

```py
print ('list1, list2')
for i in range(len(list1)):
    print(list1[i], ',', list2[i])
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Just out of curiosity, is there any other way to do this without using the zip() function?

Comment: @somethingsomewhere those the list both has the same length?

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that [```zip()```](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) will do the pairing taking into consideration the list with less elements. So, if you have one list with 10 elements and other with 11 elements, only the first 10 pairs will be generated.

Comment: @accdias you are right, this is way i asked him the question, its my fault to dont ask it before :)

Comment: @Reznik yes, they are the same length :)

Comment: @Reznik, take advantage of [```f-strings```](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/). Change ```print(f, ',', s)``` to ```print(f'{f}, {s}')```, it make the code a lot more readable (IMHO).

Comment: @somethingsomewhere edited, now without zip, if it works for you mark it as currect answer :)

Comment: @accdias as he didnt specifice the python version he used in the post i couldn't know that and wrote something that run both on python2 and python3

Answer (score 0):

As other answers mention, use `zip`, however I would also advise using string padding to line them up:

```
template = '{:>5}, {:>5}'
print('list1  list2')
print('-----  -----')
for one, two in zip(list1, list2):
    print(template.format(one, two))
```